# Mongoose Populate Returning null due to Schema design?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm stuck with mongoose populate returning null. I have a very similar situation to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770682/cant-get-mongoose-js-subdocument-array-to-populate) where it seems to we working just fine, perhaps with one important difference:
The model I'm referencing only exist as a subdocument to another model.

Example:

```
// The model i want to populate
Currency = new Schema({
  code:   String,
  rate:   Number
});


// The set of currencies are defined for each Tenant
// A currency belongs to one tenant, one tenant can have multiple currencies
Tenant = new Schema({
  name:   String,
  currencies:   [Currency]
});


Product = new Schema({
  Name:      String, 
  _currency:  {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Currency'},
});


Customer = new Schema({
  tenant:      {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Tenant'}, 
  products:    [ Product ]
});
```

Then I export the models and use them in one of my routes where what I would like to do is something like

```
CustomerModel.find({}).populate('products._currency').exec(function(err, docs){
   // docs[0].products[0]._currency is null (but has ObjectId if not usinn populate)
})
```

Which is returning null for any given product._currency but if I don't populate i get the correct ObjectId ref, which corresponds to an objectId of a currency embedded in a tenant.

I'm suspecting I need currencies to be stand-alone schema for this to work., Ie not just embedded in tenant, but that would mean I get a lot of schemas referencing each other.

Do you know if this is the case, or should my set-up work?
If this is the case, I guess I just have to bite the bullet and have multitude of collections referencing each other?

Any help or guidance appreciated!

Comment: You are correct that a `ref` only works with `populate` if the referenced doc isn't embedded.

Comment: Perhaps it should have been obvious but it did take me some time to realise this might be the issue. @JohnnyHK, thanks a lot for your answer confirming it!