# How to populate an array of object that hold and array of objects in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

is there a way to populate "from" and "to" which are a users id ?

```
[
{
    "_id": "618db265aa02b3a5a8d5af88",
    "messages": [
        {
            "message": "hi",
            "from": "61733c0dca7365ad56cb568f",
            "to": "6172bd554f33ecfa12de2bb1",
            "received": "delivered",
            "createdAt": "2021-11-12T00:15:50.060Z",
            "_id": "618db265aa02b3a5a8d5af89"
        }
}
```

]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get Mongoose.js Subdocument Array to populate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770682/cant-get-mongoose-js-subdocument-array-to-populate)

Comment: No. because the user id i want to populate (from and to) are deep inside an array of objects with an array of objects so my question is how do i target them ?.